# Plot graph for every dataset entry

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

So this is my dataset:

```
raw_data = {'first_name': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'], 
            'last_name': ['Miller', 'Jacobson', 'Ali', 'Milner', 'Cooze'], 
            'female': [0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
            'age': [42, 52, 36, 24, 73], 
            'preTestScore': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3],
            'postTestScore': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70]}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'age', 'female', 'preTestScore', 'postTestScore'])
```

I'm new to plotting data and a bit lost here. I want to plot a line for each person, where the x-ticks are `preTestScore` and `postTestScore` and the y-ticks go from 0 to 100 (the possible range of test scores).

I was thinking that I could just make a scatter plot but then I wouldn't know how to connect the dots.

Comment: Are you trying to create a [slopegraph](http://www.storytellingwithdata.com/blog/2018/6/1/swdchallenge-slopegraph)?

Comment: Ah yes, exactly what I was looking for. I didn't know what it was called. I found [this](https://gist.github.com/treycausey/97694490d2ca368e7141) and changed the code for my needs. It's not particular pretty, but it does the trick, ty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8fhD.png)

A slopegrahp was what I was looking for. Thanks @mostlyoxygen

```
x = df.loc[:, "preTestScore":"postTestScore"]
x["full_name"] = df["first_name"] + " " + df["last_name"]

num_students = x.shape[0]
num_times = x.shape[1] - 1


plt.xlim(0, 1)
plt.ylim(0, 100)
plt.xticks(np.arange(2), ["perTestScore", "postTestScore"])

plt.title("Score changes after Test taking")
plt.ylabel("Testscore")

for row in x.values:
    plt.plot([0, 1], [row[0], row[1]], label=row[2])

plt.legend(loc="best")
plt.show()
```